# How do I install chemsuite? Getting "configure: error: Can't find X includes" when I attempt to compile

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I extracted the [tarball](http://chemsuite.seul.org/chemsuite-0.0.7.tar.bz2), cd'ed to the directory, ran `./build` as per the INSTALL file in said directory directed me to do. But it told me I needed a package called "X" and I've searched for such a package and can't find it. This is the exact message it gave me:

```
...
checking for X... configure: error: Can't find X includes. Please check your installation and add the correct paths!
Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably overcome that particular error by installing the `xorg-dev` metapackage.

However the `REQUIREMENTS` file for the tarball says the package requires Qt 2.3.1 and the project web page does not appear to have been updated since 2002, so you will likely have other unmet dependencies and/or version incompatibilities that will make building it challenging.